# Configure two webservers on the same LAN

Tags: networking, dns, ip

I am trying to setup the network for a small business using a network configuration I am new to.  The business has one public IP(135.x.x.x) and wants to use separate machines for it's website (www.example.com on 192.168.1.50) and sharepoint site (sharepoint.example.com on 192.168.1.75).  The DC is on 192.168.1.10

I have added DNS Host A records for the sites pointing to the private IP address of the hosting machine.  From inside the LAN, all users can access the web and sharepoint sites.  But from an external PC, the websites return a 401 error.

Not sure whether my problem is topology, DNS, firewalls, or if the concept is simply not possible with only one public IP.

Comment: Duplicate of http://serverfault.com/questions/543902/configure-two-webservers-on-the-same-lan

Comment: This question appears to be a duplicate of a question already on another site.


Comment: Please do not post the same question across Stack Exchange sites. If necessary your question would have been migrated across to the most relevant site. As it is this question should be closed as your copy on Server fault will likely elicit the most relevant answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The business has one public IP(135.x.x.x) and wants to use separate machines for it's website

You either need to: get a second IP, make one of the servers listen on an alternate port (with appropriate port forwards). or you need to set up a reverse proxy to actually receive the port 80 associated with your public IP, and then forward them to the correct internal host based on the HTTP Host: header.